# Seleção de palavras para formação de frase

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, grid

Para facilitar a explicação, separei o seguinte mockup:

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/5l2yih.png]

A ideia é a seguinte:

Cada uma das opções na DIV está originalmente não visível, a ideia é que uma opção fique visível apenas após o clique do usuário. Além disso, a opção clicada é transferida pra última `div`, onde é criada uma sentença com base nas escolhas dos usuários nos três boxes.

Como posso fazer para fazer com que o usuário escolha apenas uma opção por box (ao selecionar uma, a seleção anterior é esquecida/bloqueada)? E como posso transferir essas escolhas pra última `div`, onde uma sentença será formada?

Comment: A imagem não carrega.

Comment: Parece normal aqui. De qualquer forma, aqui vai um mirror http://imgur.com/OgHfLHe

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta para incluir a parte relevante do código que você já tem, por favor? Dará uma ideia melhor de como responder.

Comment: Utilize JQuery, assim quando o usuário clica em uma opção as outras sejam esquecidas/limpas(não vou me aprofundar porquê você acha muita coisa no Google sobre alteração de estilo e outros afins com JQuery).

Comment: Por examplo, o usuário clicou na box 1: [box0], [*box1*], [box2]; quando ele clicar na [box2] você esquece as outras boxes: [box0], [box1], [*box2*]. Já a transferência você pode ir pegando os cliques e salvar numa array e no fim utilizar o método .append() e inserir na última div. Viu como JQuery é incrível?

Comment: Isso me lembrou muito dessa tirinha: [http://xkcd.com/1350/](http://xkcd.com/1350/)!

Comment: Seria algo parecido com isso http://jsfiddle.net/zpykZ/ ??

Comment: @ErlonCharles seria interessante você publicar o que você fez como resposta.

Comment: Eu primeiro queria saber dela se é pelo menos algo parecido com isso, se for e tiver alguma ressalva eu publico como resposta e vou fazendo as modificações.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar jQuery? Se sim, espero que este código te ajude.

Você pode atribuir uma id para cada opção? Se sim, isso vai deixar a lógica mais simples - e a seleção através do DOM mais rápida.

```
  sentenca = []; // criamos uma array para guardar as divs selecionadas

    $('.selectable').click(function(){

      //ao cliclar na div...

      $(this).addClass('visible'); //adicionamos uma classe para tornar seu conteúdo visível

      var myId = $(this).attr('id');  //vamos pegar a id da div
      sentenca.push(myID);  //e guardá-la na array

      if(sentenca.length >= 3){

        // se ela tiver mais de 3 divs, vamos apagar a 4a mais velha
        sentenca.splice(4, 1);
      }

    for (var i=0;i<sentenca.length;i++){

      //agora vamos passear pela array

      //vamos colocar na ultima div (nome 'receiver') clones das 3 últimas divs selecionadas
      $('#receiver').append(
        $('#'+sentenca[i]).clone()
        );

    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize angular.js para criar um binding entre os divs e modelos. Use ng-click para executar metodos de seleção localizados no controller.